# Free vector graphic images, for commercial use

Tags: vector, resource-recommendations, stock-images

Is there a free library of vector graphics for commercial use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also check out http://openclipart.org/. And from the companion site, inkscape.org you can download Inkscape an easy-to-use, free, and cross-platform vector graphics program.

Comment: Thanks, it clearly states that its default licence is Creative Commons 0, that is, equivalent to public domain. Although, it would be even better if there would be more advanced search features.

Comment: Yes, public domain, and it would be even better better if it had an AI search feature and if it would pay you money for using their clipart. It is totally free and free of charge and done by volunteers (including me). So if you want better search results, please become a librarian (like me) and help with the tagging and with better descriptions.

Answer (score 9):

## 2016

### Creative Commons CC0 license & Public Domain:

Sites that exclusively list images in the public domain or with a [Creative Commons CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/) (or equivalent) license.

- [Public Domain Vectors](http://publicdomainvectors.org/)
- [openclipart](https://openclipart.org/)
- [clker](http://www.clker.com/)
- [Pixabay](https://pixabay.com/en/photos/?image_type=vector) <sup>(Not exclusively vector art but easily filterable)</sup>

---

### Not exclusively free or variable licences

Sites that list vectors for sale and offer free vectors and/or sites that offer vectors with different licenses—These may require attribution, for example. Always check the relevant licenses when downloading.

- [Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com/) <sup>(Vector Icons—attribution required for free downloads)</sup>
- [logolagoon](http://logolagoon.com/category/freebies/) <sup>(Vector Logos—'Freebies' section)</sup>
- [vectorstock](https://www.vectorstock.com/free-vectors) <sup>(Paid & Free Vectors—Free licenses for personal and evaluation use only)</sup>
- [vectorscout](http://vectorscout.com/) <sup>(Personal & Commercial licences)</sup>
- [vecteezy](http://www.vecteezy.com/) <sup>(Individually licensed—Some requiring attribution)</sup>
- [Free Vector](http://www.freevector.com/) <sup>(Individually licensed—Some requiring attribution)</sup>
- [freepik](http://www.freepik.com/) <sup>(Free for commercial use with attribution—Premium licenses available)</sup>
- [Vector Portal](http://www.vectorportal.com/) <sup>(Individually licensed—Some requiring attribution)</sup>
- [Q Vectors](http://qvectors.net/) <sup>(Individually licensed—Some requiring attribution)</sup>
- [Vector4Free](http://vector4free.com/) <sup>(Individually licensed—Some requiring attribution)</sup>
- [Vector Open Stock](https://www.vectoropenstock.com/) <sup>(Individually licensed—Some requiring attribution)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Be very careful of using free vectors from sites like these. A lot of the work is stolen content from stock sites like Shutterstock and iStock or traced copyright designs. 
If you are making designs for clients I would not advise using any of those sites.

A couple of good options are [GraphiRiver](http://www.graphicriver.net) and [Vector Stock](http://www.vectorstock.com/). They have many images for $1 for commercial usage and some free vectors too.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a site that is specifically for commercial use, but there are a number of free vector sites which list specific licenses for each image. Many of them use creative commons license which makes it easy to know at a glance if the image you're viewing is available for commercial use.

Here are a few to get you started:

- http://www.vecteezy.com/
- http://www.freevectorsdaily.com/
- http://www.vectoropenstock.com/
- http://qvectors.net/
- http://vector4free.com/

Comment: Thanks. There are very useful sites in your list, some of then with advanced seach features, while others doesn't have accesible information about licencing, but its good to have this list handy.

Answer (score 3):

You can get free vector downloads via sites like http://vectorscout.com

Answer (score 3):

Most of [Wikimedia Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) is licensed under CC Share Alike 3.0. That means you can use it for commercial purposes.

There also a bunch of stuff that's released into the public domain.

Comment: Careful, yes you could use CC Share Alike for commercial purposes but only if you properly pass the licence and give proper attibution to the creator etc etc. This is possible in a book or magazine where you just collect all those notes on some page in small print. But almost impossible if you need to make a glossy full page advertisment or a nice video clip without minutes of end-credits.

Answer (score 1):

[Pixabay.com](http://pixabay.com/en/photos/?image_type=vector) is a substantial and reliable resource for vector graphics. All of which are published under Creative Commons CC0 as public domain. So no attribution is required and the works may be used in commercial projects without restrictions.

I'm one of the founders of Pixabay.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [LogoLagoon freebies category](http://logolagoon.com/category/freebies/).

They offer some amazing free logos (in vector format) that can be used for both personal or commercial purposes.