# Which is the Best and more reliable Free Vector Graphics Site?

Tags: vector, free

Free Vectors graphics are really popular these days... the thing is that there are a bunch of site with lot of graphics which you don't know if you can trust. I've seen a lot of stolen and pirate stuff from paid microstock in those free sites. My question is which are the most trusted/reliable sites out there.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about resource gathering. Particularly when you mention things like "which are the most trusted/reliable the answer can very, very quickly become dated. Not too mention - how should any of us know which one is doing well at any given moment in time?

Comment: You may find this protected question useful, however again, we can't promise any or all of them to be working or trustworthy: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12920/free-vector-graphic-images-for-commercial-use

Answer (score 0):

I have been exploring websites with vector graphics for a good time and I think that www.vectoropenstock.com has the best resources, very creative original vectors of high quality. Also vectorportal.com and Vecteezy.com have nice colections of vectors too. Do you know these sites?

Answer (score -1):

It's basically impossible to be 100% on the safe side with *free* images. The best options probably are

[Pixabay](http://pixabay.com/en/photos/?image_type=vector) and [Openclipart.org](https://openclipart.org/)

You can use "Google Search by Image" to see where selected images are being published already. This can give you an idea if the image is really free. Google tends to list images that are fro sale on microstock sites, such as Shutterstock or iStock, on top of the search results. If you find an image there, it's often illegally published as free image on your source site.

I'm one of the founders of Pixabay, by the way.