# Where can I get flat images for a website?

Tags: website-design, images, flat-design, minimalistic

I'm building a new website but am finding a lack of minimalistic images and clipart. This is a very general question but are there any good sites to find minimal, flat, simple, etc. images?

I have seen low poly art but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We have two questions you might want to look at --- (1) Photos: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6799/where-can-i-get-images-for-commercial-use --- (2) Vectors: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12920/free-vector-graphic-images-for-commercial-use ---- if neither of those help then consider [edit] your question to something more specific and include WHY existing solutions havent worked

Answer (score 3):

I can not personally recommend a website to find what you are looking for due to the fact I create my own, I will suggest using more precise terms when attempting a search query. If you are looking for buttons, icons, and other such things. Using these terms will allow you to better sort through the vast amount of images. Don't forget to use the term 'Vector' in place of clip art. When developing sites I prefer PNG formats and vectors for the loss-less re-sizing ability.

There are plenty of companies out there that have sites that do offer great images for websites, be prepared to fork over some cash for licensing. If you are not part of communities like Adobe's [Stock Adobe](https://stock.adobe.com/) I would suggest that as a next step if you are not prepare to create your own designs.