# Special shape in Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I was wondering how can I create a shape like this one? In Photoshop there are several options with Brushes and I think you could do the same thing in Illustrator.  But my question is, how can I create a shape like this?

Thank you! and have a nice day[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU3Fg.jpg)

Comment: Well, I was thinking draw i with the Pen Tool from 0 but I was wondering if there's a way to do it faster and easier.  Or maybe I can download the shape like I download brushes and styles

Comment: @Majo its possible to download it but you can also create this in less time than searching for a download (it takes a minute or less to draw). Once crated you can reuse it as many times as possible.

Comment: Yes @joojaa, that's what I was looking for, something I could reuse.  So I tried and I drew it quickly, right now I'm correcting it :) Thanks for taking the time and answer

Answer (score 1):

Options:

- [Free vector graphic images, for commercial use](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12920/free-vector-graphic-images-for-commercial-use)
- Draw with `Pen` tool as you were doing
- Find a thin font with a nice brace glyph { to use as a foundation. In just a few seconds with no tweaking I got this (I used the font Onyx which is a bit thicker than what you showed):

[image: Braces]

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer! I'll check the link you game me... I decided for the Pen Tool option, because I didn't get the font thing :P I think it's good but I will try again because I think it needs some improvements.  Thank you very  much ;)